# Grails Domain Class unit Testing

Tags: grails

when I rename the default method name testSomething() method in unit test to something else, I get the "No runnable " error message. I am wondering should I change the setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using jUnit 3 this can help you: "with JUnit 3, to define a test it was mandatory that the class name was named like MyClassTest, be extending from TestCase and all the test method names were starting with 'test' as in 'testMyMethod()'"

http://java.dzone.com/articles/unit-test-naming-conventions